# Keep daily granularity in time difference when filling null values or casting to integer

Tags: python, python-polars

I am computing the time difference between two dates, this works perfectly fine:

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": pl.date_range(date(2023, 1, 1), date(2023, 1, 3))})

print(df.with_columns([(pl.col("a") - pl.col("a").shift(1))]))
# shape: (3, 1)
# ┌──────────────┐
# │ a            │
# │ ---          │
# │ duration[ms] │
# ╞══════════════╡
# │ null         │
# │ 1d           │
# │ 1d           │
# └──────────────┘
```

Given I am working with lagged variables, I'd like to fill the nan values originated by lagging the second variable. Using `.fill_null(0)` converts the entire column to a `int64` unit, with values converted to a millisecond granularity.

```py
# Filling null values brings everything to the ms unit
print(df.with_columns([(pl.col("a") - pl.col("a").shift(1)).fill_null(0)]))
# shape: (3, 1)
# ┌──────────┐
# │ a        │
# │ ---      │
# │ i64      │
# ╞══════════╡
# │ 0        │
# │ 86400000 │
# │ 86400000 │
# └──────────┘
```

Which forces me to bring them back to a daily granularity with a simple division:

```py
# Which forces to a division to bring everything back to days
print(
    df.with_columns(
        [((pl.col("a") - pl.col("a").shift(1)).fill_null(0) / 86400000).cast(pl.UInt64)]
    )
)
# shape: (3, 1)
# ┌─────┐
# │ a   │
# │ --- │
# │ u64 │
# ╞═════╡
# │ 0   │
# │ 1   │
# │ 1   │
# └─────┘
```

I am wondering if there is anything more practical and concise than this to keep values as integers representing a day. I am perfectly fine with handling the unit myself but this can become quite verbose when working with a lot of columns.

I guess this is not currently supported as *us*, *ns*, and *ms* are the only units currently supported by [`pl.Duration`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Duration.html#polars-duration).

##### Complete reprex

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": pl.date_range(date(2023, 1, 1), date(2023, 1, 3))})

print(df.with_columns([(pl.col("a") - pl.col("a").shift(1))]))
# Filling null values brings everything to the ms unit
print(df.with_columns([(pl.col("a") - pl.col("a").shift(1)).fill_null(0)]))
# Which forces to a division to bring everything back to days
print(
    df.with_columns(
        [((pl.col("a") - pl.col("a").shift(1)).fill_null(0) / 86400000).cast(pl.UInt64)]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about filling with `dt.timedelta(days=0)`?

```py
In [72]: df.with_columns([(pl.col("a") - pl.col("a").shift(1)).fill_null(dt.timedelta(days=0))])
Out[72]:
shape: (3, 1)
┌──────────────┐
│ a            │
│ ---          │
│ duration[ms] │
╞══════════════╡
│ 0ms          │
│ 1d           │
│ 1d           │
└──────────────┘
```

Comment: is that `datetime.timedelta`?  You can use pl.duration in the same way.